# Looping through python regex matches

Tags: python, regex, string, loops

I want to turn a string that looks like this:

```
ABC12DEF3G56HIJ7
```

into

```
12 * ABC
3  * DEF
56 * G
7  * HIJ
```

I want to construct the correct set of loops using regex matching. The crux of the issue is that the code has to be completely general because I cannot assume how long the `[A-Z]` fragments will be, nor how long the `[0-9]` fragments will be.

Comment: `''.join("%s * %s\n" % (n, w) for w, n in re.findall(r'(?i)([a-z]+)(\d+)', input_string))`

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Python's `re.findall` should work for you.

[Live demo](http://codepad.org/70EHhuI1)

```
import re

s = "ABC12DEF3G56HIJ7"
pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)')

for (letters, numbers) in re.findall(pattern, s):
    print(numbers, '*', letters)
```

Answer (score 95):

It is better to use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer) if your dataset is large because that reduces memory consumption (`findall()` return a list of all results, `finditer()` finds them one by one).

```
import re

s = "ABC12DEF3G56HIJ7"
pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)')

for m in re.finditer(pattern, s):
    print m.group(2), '*', m.group(1)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the last line of this example should be `print m.group(2), '*', m.group(1)` to fit the OP's desired output.  I believe that `m.group(0)` is the 'full' match--i.e., ABC12, DEF3, G56, HIJ7.

Comment: @DaveL17 You are right, thanks. I didn't think much while write this answer, fixed now.

Comment: This method has the benefit of letting you access named groups by name, rather than by location in the regular expression (which might change if the patterns are moved in the regular expression.)

Comment: Why is that better?

Comment: @Jann Poppinga reduce memory usage.  `findall` get  all result back, `finditer` get one by one .

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the OP's post, the format of the output seems to matter. The * is aligned to max length of the number.

If that is the case, then this example produces the desired output:

```
import re

s = "ABC12DEF3G56HIJ7"

pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)')

key_length = 0

matches = pattern.findall(s)

for (_, key) in matches:
    key_length = max(key_length, len(key))

for (value, key) in matches:
    print(f"{key:<{key_length}} * {value}")
```

This could be done in a more pythonic way, such as with list comprehension, but this has been avoided for clarity.

E.g the output for `s = "ABC1215431DEF3G56HIJ7"` would/should be:

```
1215431 * ABC
3       * DEF
56      * G  
7       * HIJ
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler one liner would be

```
print(re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", r'\2 * \1\n', s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option could be to use `re.sub()` to create the desired strings from the captured groups:

```py
import re
s = 'ABC12DEF3G56HIJ7'
for x in re.sub(r"([A-Z]+)(\d+)", r'\2 * \1,', s).rstrip(',').split(','):
    print(x)

12 * ABC
3 * DEF
56 * G
7 * HIJ
```