# program that detects all digits in an input string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

input:

```
I am 52 years old. The 48a24 is an example.
```

output:

```
52, 48, 24
```

this is my code:

```
string=''
string=input()

def finddigits(string):
    digits=''
    string.split()
    for i in string:
        if i.isdigit():
            digits += i
    return digits

res = [int(i) for i in string.split() if i.isdigit()]
print(finddigits(string))
```

but my output is not same with what i want

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @shabnam Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I think your question is definitely something that a new user would find challenging, however you should be a little sensitive to the fact that people don't like answering ["homework" questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) over here. A good question would have a better title and would detail out where exactly you were stuck and needed help with.

Comment: sorry if my question bothering you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to do this.

There is a very similar question here: [Looping through python regex matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870178/looping-through-python-regex-matches)

You would just need a slightly different reg expression than the one in the answer from above.

A regex string: `([0-9]+)` would give you the answer you want.

Examining the regex above:

- The parenthesis `()` are for capturing a group, this is the a piece of the input that you want as an output.
- The square brackets `[]` is a regex class.
- The `0-9` means any number between 0 and 9.
- The `+` after the `[]` means 1 or more class matches.

So in this case `[0-9]` means match any single digit number. `[0-9]+` match any number, and any digit after that.

You can test your regular expressions on this website: https://regex101.com/

---

Just give me the code:

```
import re;

s = "I am 52 years old. The 48a24 is an example"
pattern = re.compile(r'([0-9]+)');

for group in re.findall(pattern, s):
    print(group)
```

Gives output:

```
52
48
24
```

Comment: can you please check my code and tell me how i fix the output

Comment: I think the issue is that you just add digits and never 'reset' the digits after a non-digit character is reached. I.e.: if i is not a digit start a new number/put a comma in your string.

Answer (score 0):

your string.split() is list of words from input string. in your ex `I am 52 years old. The 48a24 is an example`, only '52' is valid digit and evaluates True for isdigit(). 'some-string'.isdigit() evaluates true when some-string is does not contain any alphabet or special charecters.